# html font-awesome icon won't show

Tags: html, laravel, font-awesome

I'm using [assan template](http://bootstraplovers.com/assan-kit-3.8/bootstrap4/website-templates/creative-onepage/html/index.html)

to build my laravel project. Everything is fine but the font awesome wont show up. then I'm using this link to fix it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css">
```

after that, font awesome showed successfully, but the icons not. Here is the code where i put my icon:

```
<i class='icon-pictures fa-3x mb20 text-primary'></i>
```

I'm pretty sure that i've already include all java script and css to my project. but I don't know why this happen. is there something i can do or maybe i missed something?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Answer (score 0):

The method for displaying an icon is that you have to use "fas fa-" following with which icon you want.
In the `<i>` class add fas fa- and the icon name after the -, This will display the icon.